# Splitting a string on a new line into seperate variable

Tags: java

so I have a variable id that outputs

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I just want to grab the first number 1 and add that as student1.id
and the second number as student2.id and so on.

currently, if I print student1.id I get

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

how would i go about this? i tried doing a for loop but it said it is not iteratable.

```
public class main { 
    /**
    * Reads a text file containing student data and uses this to populate the student objects
    *
    * @param filename Path to the student data file to be read
    * @return Whether the file was read successfully
    */
    public static boolean readFile(String filename) { File file = new File(filename);
    try {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    String[] words = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
    addStudent(words[0],words[1],words[2],words[3],words[4],words[5],words[6],words[7],words[8]); // TODO: Finish adding the parameters
    }
    scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { System.out.println("Failed to read file");
    }
    return true;
    }

static void addStudent(String id, String firstName, String lastName, String mathsMark1, String mathsMark2, String mathsMark3, String englishMark1, String englishMark2, String englishMark3) {

    Student student1 = new Student();
    Student student2 = new Student();
    Student student3 = new Student();
    Student student4 = new Student();
    Student student5 = new Student();

    student1.id = id;
    student1.firstname = firstName;
    student1.lastname = lastName;


      System.out.println(student1.id);



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `split(",")`. Either provide the input as `1,2,3,4,5` or change the code to `split(" ")`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file contains integer elements separated by comma. I would create a `List<Student>` and store the `words` to each of list elements like so

```
List<Student> students = new Arraylist<>();

for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    Student s1 = new Student();
    s1.id = Intger.parseInt(words[i]); // since words is String[]
    students.add(s1)
}
```

In your snippet you created 5 `Student` objects but are using only the first one.

To output just use a for loop like so...

```
for (Student student: students) {
    System.out.println(student.id);
}
```

Comment: yes they are just place holders for now, they are strings not intergers

Comment: Updated to insert integer elements as id. BTW you should use getter and setters instead of assigning ids with equals operator